# How to Implement Server Side Error Handling for Web Socket

Tags: c#, websocket

I want to implement all types error Handling for web socket implementation at server side.

### My Server Side Code

```
public class WebSocketManager : WebSocketHandler
{

    public override void OnOpen()
    {
       // Do when Connection Is Open
    }

    public override void OnClose()
    {
      // Close Connection
    }

    public override void OnMessage(string message)
    {
       // When Any Message Sent to Client
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add exception handling using try catch blocks and log the errors to a log file. Like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2344/Create-Simple-Error-Log-Files-using-ASP-NET-and-C

Or you can log them to the event viewer if you want.

Comment: I want to catch specific errors which is generated for web socket.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803971/websocket-onerror-how-to-read-error-description