# Handling asynchronous JavaScript Chrome Console Errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I have some Javascript in a Chrome Extension that runs every 3 seconds and attempts to make a connection to a local WebSocket Server.

```
setInterval(attemptConnection, 3000);

function attemptConnection() {

try {
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById(JsonObject.elementTagValue).setAttribute("value", JsonObject.valueToSet);

    }
}

catch(err) {
//do something here
    }
```

I only expect to be running a local WebSocket server at certain points in time.  If a connection is made, the WebSocket Server will send some JSON data that the javascript will use immediately.

When I go into the developer tools, I see that I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the console many times because there is obviously nothing at that end-point and that is expected behavior.  Is there a way to suppress those console outputs or handle this issue better?

EDIT - Updated the code and I still get errors output to the console

```
setInterval(attemptConnection, 3000);

function attemptConnection() {
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById(JsonObject.elementTagValue).setAttribute("value", JsonObject.valueToSet);
        exampleSocket.send(event.data);

        exampleSocket.onerror = function () {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you use `exampleSocket.onerror`?

Comment: `try/catch` doesn't work because the error happens asynchronously.

Comment: Network errors always are logged to console, regardless whether they're handled in JS or not. You can hide them through the devtools settings, though

Comment: Is there a risk of flooding the console with a ton of errors? I hope I am not going to bring Chrome crashing down if I left the browser open for a long time.

Comment: Half-baked idea: is there a way to check if the connection will succeed before calling `new WebSocket('...')`? I haven't looked into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that you have to handle errors with `onerror` you should handle the `onclose` as well.
The simplest check is the error code `1000` that means a normal socket close

```
exampleSocket.onclose = (event) => {
   if (event.code != 1000) {
      // "Normal closure, meaning that the purpose for which the connection was established has been fulfilled.";
   }
}
```

While a complete handling of error codes is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803971/websocket-onerror-how-to-read-error-description), and I'm putting here for your convenience:

```
     exampleSocket.onclose = (event) => {
        if (event.code == 1000)
            reason = "Normal closure, meaning that the purpose for which the connection was established has been fulfilled.";
        else if(event.code == 1001)
            reason = "An endpoint is \"going away\", such as a server going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.";
        else if(event.code == 1002)
            reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection due to a protocol error";
        else if(event.code == 1003)
            reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a type of data it cannot accept (e.g., an endpoint that understands only text data MAY send this if it receives a binary message).";
        else if(event.code == 1004)
            reason = "Reserved. The specific meaning might be defined in the future.";
        else if(event.code == 1005)
            reason = "No status code was actually present.";
        else if(event.code == 1006)
           reason = "The connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close control frame";
        else if(event.code == 1007)
            reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received data within a message that was not consistent with the type of the message (e.g., non-UTF-8 [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629] data within a text message).";
        else if(event.code == 1008)
            reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that \"violates its policy\". This reason is given either if there is no other sutible reason, or if there is a need to hide specific details about the policy.";
        else if(event.code == 1009)
           reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that is too big for it to process.";
        else if(event.code == 1010) // Note that this status code is not used by the server, because it can fail the WebSocket handshake instead.
            reason = "An endpoint (client) is terminating the connection because it has expected the server to negotiate one or more extension, but the server didn't return them in the response message of the WebSocket handshake. <br /> Specifically, the extensions that are needed are: " + event.reason;
        else if(event.code == 1011)
            reason = "A server is terminating the connection because it encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.";
        else if(event.code == 1015)
            reason = "The connection was closed due to a failure to perform a TLS handshake (e.g., the server certificate can't be verified).";
        else
            reason = "Unknown reason";
     }
```

```js
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log(JsonObject)
        exampleSocket.send(event.data);

        exampleSocket.onerror = function () {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
exampleSocket.onclose = (event) => {
            if (event.code == 1000)
                reason = "Normal closure, meaning that the purpose for which the connection was established has been fulfilled.";
            else if(event.code == 1001)
                reason = "An endpoint is \"going away\", such as a server going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.";
            else if(event.code == 1002)
                reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection due to a protocol error";
            else if(event.code == 1003)
                reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a type of data it cannot accept (e.g., an endpoint that understands only text data MAY send this if it receives a binary message).";
            else if(event.code == 1004)
                reason = "Reserved. The specific meaning might be defined in the future.";
            else if(event.code == 1005)
                reason = "No status code was actually present.";
            else if(event.code == 1006)
               reason = "The connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close control frame";
            else if(event.code == 1007)
                reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received data within a message that was not consistent with the type of the message (e.g., non-UTF-8 [http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629] data within a text message).";
            else if(event.code == 1008)
                reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that \"violates its policy\". This reason is given either if there is no other sutible reason, or if there is a need to hide specific details about the policy.";
            else if(event.code == 1009)
               reason = "An endpoint is terminating the connection because it has received a message that is too big for it to process.";
            else if(event.code == 1010) // Note that this status code is not used by the server, because it can fail the WebSocket handshake instead.
                reason = "An endpoint (client) is terminating the connection because it has expected the server to negotiate one or more extension, but the server didn't return them in the response message of the WebSocket handshake. <br /> Specifically, the extensions that are needed are: " + event.reason;
            else if(event.code == 1011)
                reason = "A server is terminating the connection because it encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.";
            else if(event.code == 1015)
                reason = "The connection was closed due to a failure to perform a TLS handshake (e.g., the server certificate can't be verified).";
            else
                reason = "Unknown reason";
                console.error(reason);
         }
```

I have added here a full WebSocket client wrapper that handles reconnect as well by means of `autoReconnectInterval` and `maxAttempts` through a simple reconnect logic (porting from WebSocket node official examples).

```js
function WebSocketClient() {
  this.number = 0; // Message number
  this.autoReconnectInterval = 5 * 1000; // ms
  this.maxAttempts = 3;
  this.attempts = 0;
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.open = function(url) {
  var self = this;
  this.url = url;

  this.instance = new WebSocket(this.url);
  this.instance.onopen = () => {
    self.onopen();
  }
  this.instance.onmessage = (data, flags) => {
    self.number++;
    self.onmessage(data, flags, this.number);
  }
  this.instance.onclose = (e) => {
    switch (e) {
      case 1000: // CLOSE_NORMAL
        console.log("WebSocket: closed normally");
        break;
      default: // Abnormal closure
        if (self.attempts < self.maxAttempts) self.reconnect(e);
        self.attempts++;
        break;
    }
    this.onclose(e);
  }
  this.instance.onerror = (e) => {
    switch (e.code) {
      case 'ECONNREFUSED':
        self.reconnect(e);
        break;
      default:
        self.onerror(e);
        break;
    }
  }
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.send = function(data, option) {
  try {
    this.instance.send(data, option);
  } catch (e) {
    this.instance.emit('error', e);
  }
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.reconnect = function(e) {
  var self = this;

  console.log("WebSocketClient: retry in %s ms attempt %d", self.autoReconnectInterval, self.attempts);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("WebSocketClient: reconnecting...");
    self.open(self.url);
  }, self.autoReconnectInterval);
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient: open", arguments);
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.onmessage = function(data, flags, number) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient: message", data);
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient: error");
}
WebSocketClient.prototype.onclose = function(e) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient: closed");
}

var wsc = new WebSocketClient();
wsc.open('wss://localhost:8080/');
wsc.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient connected:", e);
  this.send("echo");
}
wsc.onmessage = function(data, flags, number) {
  console.log("WebSocketClient message", data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I I tried that but I still am outputting errors to the console.  I dont think the socket is ever opened, the error is occuring while the connection is being attempted.

Comment: I have added a code snippet, run it in your client and tell me which is the error code.

Comment: Console outputs "The connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or receiving a Close control frame" and
"ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: Ok so it is error code `1006`. This means that the Control frame (Close, Ping or Pong) has not been sent. Is your WebSocket client code all in the above snippet? The WebSocker server is sending this special code for a abnormal client execution.

Comment: I have included all the client javascript code for the Chrome extension.  The Web Socket server runs local on the client (it is just a way to pass values to Chrome - another process triggers the server to start).  However, the server is not running when I am getting that error, so I assume that error 1006 is generated regardless of whether a connection is made or not.

Comment: @JasonBayldon Ok, so you need a retry logic and error code detection, please check out my last snippet then!

Comment: Thanks.  However, I am still outputting a bunch of 'WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8080/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED' errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143448/discussion-between-loretoparisi-and-jason-bayldon).

Comment: Accepting your answer since it is the most comprehensive for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `try/catch` to catch this error because it happens asynchronously. You should use an `onerror` event handler.

```
function attemptConnection() {
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
    exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById(JsonObject.elementTagValue).setAttribute("value", JsonObject.valueToSet);

    };
    exampleSocket.onerror = function() {
        // do nothing
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have realized that.  However, I am still generating errors in the console.

Comment: It might not be possible to suppress them.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to only log 1 error if you clear the timeout in your error handler. You can also start another Timeout in your onmessage function so it will only run when it is getting messages. Give it a try

```
var timer = null;

function attemptConnection() {
    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

        exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
        timer = setTimeout(attemptConnection, 100);
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById(JsonObject.elementTagValue).setAttribute("value", JsonObject.valueToSet);
        exampleSocket.send(event.data);
    }
    exampleSocket.onerror = function (event) {
          console.log('error')
            //do nothin
          clearTimeout(timer)

      }
}

attemptConnection();
```

Comment: The issue is that while browsing I don't know when the socket server is going to be available so I poll it continuously.