# Websocket error details

Tags: angular, websocket, ionic3

I have an ionic angular app where i am using websocket client to communicate with server. It is failing and I am unable to get the error details for the failures. the code looks like below

```
 ws.addEventListener('error', (event:any) => {
      console.error("The socket had an error", event);
      alert('event is:' + event.message)
      this.messageQueue.presentToast("Error connecting to chat server",false,0)
    });
```

the event.message is undefined. So how do i find what exact error is coming here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websocket onerror - how to read error description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803971/websocket-onerror-how-to-read-error-description)

Comment: checked that. i do not hit close event. I am hitting error event only. so need to get details in the error function

Comment: You don't, but the protocol does. Anytime an error condition occurs, the connection is closed. The corresponding simple error is sent under this condition - just as the other reference discusses.

Comment: not happening in my case. i dont see connection closed at all